# import org.openqa.selenium.By not found despite of maven dependency has been added

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, maven-3

I'm following a [tutorial about Selenium with Java](https://www.airpair.com/selenium/posts/selenium-tutorial-with-java). I had followed the instructions and add maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>io.ddavison</groupId>
     <artifactId>conductor</artifactId>
     <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then run `mvn install`

But when I create the class "HomePage", with an import to `org.openqa.selenium.By`, IntelliJ saids:  `Cannot resolve symbol 'openqa'`

```
package com.mysite.selenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

public class HomePage {
    // the tabs
    public static final String LOC_LNK_PROJECTSTAB = "li#menu_projects a[href$='projects/']";
    public static final String LOC_LNK_DOWNLOADTAB = "li#menu_download a[href$='download/']";
    public static final By LOC_LNK_DOCUMENTATIONTAB = By.xpath("//li[@id='menu_documentation']/a[contains(@href, 'docs/')]");
    public static final String LOC_LNK_SUPPORTTAB = "li#menu_support a[href$='support/']";
    public static final String LOC_LNK_ABOUTTAB = "li#menu_about a[href$='about/']";

    // download link
    public static final By LOC_LNK_DOWNLOADSELENIUM = By.linkText("Download Selenium");
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class [`org.openqa.selenium.By`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html) is defined in `selenium-api`, You need to add the following dependency to your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Note that the version is not mandatory to 3.11.0—you can choose another version. For example, the one used by `io.ddavison:conductor:1.1` is  [Selenium 2.43.1](https://github.com/conductor-framework/conductor/blob/v1.1/pom.xml#L109). You need to:

- Declare the same version 2.43.1 in your pom.xml
- Or update to a newer version of `io.ddavison:conductor`

Comment: I had added dependency for org.seleniumhq.selenium, version 2.43.1, and rerun mvn install but it still doesn't work

Comment: @Andiana, I created a repository for you https://github.com/mincong-h/so50185828 I cannot produce the problem that you've met. Everything works fine for me

Comment: Your repository is work for me. I can't find the differents between your and my project, but many thanks. I think the problem is solved :)

Comment: @Andiana, you're welcome. I think the difference might be hidden in IntelliJ configuration. Perhaps you created a project first, then added the Maven structure later on. While I created a Maven structure before using IntelliJ—so all the JAR files are indexed correctly.

Comment: Yes, I created the project in IntelliJ, and choose Maven in from the wizard

Comment: @Andiana, try File->Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Build Tools->Maven->Maven home directory change to Bundled (Maven 3) ?

Answer (score 0):

in 4.6 its under

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
    <version>4.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```