# Selenium installation failing with missing org.openqa.selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, maven

I'm trying to install and run Selenium (Java) on RedHat 8, using Eclipse. This is my first day with both Java and Maven (I normally do C++), and things are going pretty much as expected: it's not working, and I'm getting `package org.openqa.selenium is not visible` when I run the Maven build.

I'm going through the instructions at selenium.dev. This suggests [installing the libraries](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/selenium_installation/installing_selenium_libraries/) with Maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>3.X</version>
</dependency>
```

and the [example Java code](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/) is:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import static org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated;
import java.time.Duration;

public class HelloSelenium {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        try {
            driver.get("https://google.com/ncr");
            driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("cheese" + Keys.ENTER);
            WebElement firstResult = wait.until(presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("h3")));
            System.out.println(firstResult.getAttribute("textContent"));
        } finally {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

I've also installed geckodriver for FireFox, and this is in the path when I run eclipse.

The first problem was that version '3.X' isn't a thing, and I've replaced it with 3.9.1. The second is the message above ('package org.openqa.selenium is not visible'). There are lots of hits on the web, and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50185855/785194) says that I also need `selenium-api`, but this isn't working for me. My current pom.xml has these dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

My `~/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium` contains, I think, everything I'd expect to see from these dependencies. I've also tried adding a dependency on various levels below `org.openqa.selenium`, but it doesn't help.

Any ideas on how I can fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Got it running, as follows:

1. deleted module-info.java
2. Replaced the two dependencies with a single selenium-server
3. There seems to be a bug in the supplied test program. The compiler complained that `Duration.ofSeconds(10)` couldn't be converted to a long, so I just replaced it with the integer '10'

I then spent 15 or 20 minutes trying to work out how to actually run the output of a Maven build. It now runs Ok.